# How to loop and ask for user input

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I need help with loops.

I'm trying to  capture the input from the user and determine a hotel's cost for planning a vacation.

I have a problem looping the input so the user can pick another hotel and end the program if the user does not pick any of the keystrokes ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", or "d"), and then calculate the total cost for hotels.

I came up with this so far:

```
puts choice = gets.chomp.downcase
puts "For how many nights?"
num=gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Okay...any other hotels?"  
puts choice = gets.chomp.downcase

#Hotel Prices  

#Hotel A
if (choice== "a" or choice=="A") 
cost_2= (num/3)*500 + (num%3)*200
end

#Hotel B
if (choice=="b" or choice=="B")
cost_3= num*250
end

#Hotel C
if (choice=="c" or choice=="C")
cost_4 = (num/3)*700 + (num%3)*300
end

#Hotel D
 if (choice== "d" or choice=="D")
  cost_5= num*500
   end
```

[Hotel Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntjKw.png)

Comment: Have a look at [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).

Comment: "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" would be good reading for you.

Comment: Don't use a link to an image for information that is important to the question. Instead, copy/paste that into the question and format it appropriately. Links rot then break, and if the information in the link is essential your question will become worthless to others. Remember, your question is an article to help others solve the same problem.

Comment: As @sagarpandya82, suggests, the normal way is `loop do; ..; break if <some condition)>;...; end`. You could use (for example) `while true;..;end` or `while 1;...; end`, but `loop` is preferred. In some case you may prefer `while(<some condition>);..;end` or `until(<some condition);..;end`. One advantage of `loop` is that when the loop contains an enumerator that attempts to enumerate beyond its end, causing the enumerator to raise a `StopInteration` exception, `loop` handles the exception by breaking out of the loop. See [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible improvements to your code, but I'll keep this answer as simple and direct as I can.

Use a `loop`, and a single `if ... else if ... else ... end` block code, rather than several separate `if` statements:

```
loop do
  if (choice== "a" or choice=="A") 
    cost_2= (num/3)*500 + (num%3)*200
  #Hotel B
  elsif (choice=="b" or choice=="B")
    cost_3= num*250
  #Hotel C
  elsif (choice=="c" or choice=="C")
    cost_4 = (num/3)*700 + (num%3)*300
  #Hotel D
  elsif (choice== "d" or choice=="D")
    cost_5= num*500
  else
    puts "Final cost is: [...]"
    break
  end
end
```

You could also consider implementing a more explicit exit by saying something like `"Type 'done' when you have finished"` -- and 'ignoring' any other input that is is not a/b/c/d/done. In other words, something along the lines of:

```
# ...
elsif (choice== "d" or choice=="D")
  cost_5= num*500
elsif choice == 'done'
  puts "Final cost is: [...]"
  break
else
  puts 'Unknown option'
end
# ...
```

Comment: @theTinMan Done.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in a while loop,

```
continue = true
while continue
  ...
  if choice == "done"
    continue = false
  end
end
```

Obviously the end case can be anything, not just "done".

For the sake of completion, an elegant solution to this problem would be something like:

```
loop do
  puts choice = gets.chomp.downcase
  puts "For how many nights?"
  num=gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "Okay...any other hotels?"  
  puts choice = gets.chomp.downcase

  selections = {
     a: (num/3)*500 + (num%3)*200,
     b: num*250,
     c: (num/3)*700 + (num%3)*300,
     d: (num*500)
  }

  if selections[choice.to_sym]
    cost += selections[choice.to_sym]
  else
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: IMO it's cleaner to `break` rather than have such boolean variables floating around.

Comment: This is a good improvement however the code still needs some refactoring. There is duplicated code and this method knows too much about HOW we ask questions and how the costs are calculated . The method itself should only care about what he needs and trust other objects to do their part. Those parts about costs could be extracted out of here into classes and each of them could be injected as a dependency . Just an idea. The code will be much more stable and will only depend on the public methods of those classes ( which could implement same interface ) which would make the code more stable

Comment: Don't use `while`, use `loop`. It's idiomatic for Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

This is untested, but it's the basic idea for what I'd use:

```
loop do

  cost = nil
  loop do

    puts 'Which hotel? (A, B, C, D)'
    hotel = gets.chomp.downcase

    puts 'For how many nights?'
    days = gets.to_i

    cost = if hotel == 'a' 
             (days / 3) * 500 + (days % 3) * 200
           elsif hotel == 'b'
             days * 250
           elsif hotel == 'c'
             (days / 3) * 700 + (days % 3) * 300
           elsif hotel == 'd'
             days * 500
           else
             puts 'Unknown hotel.'
           end

    break if cost

  end

  puts cost

  puts 'Okay...any other hotels? (y/n)'  

  break unless gets.downcase.start_with?('y')    
end
```

Instead of chained `if`/`elsif`/`else`/`end` I'd use a `case` statement:

```
cost = case hotel
       when 'a' 
         (days / 3) * 500 + (days % 3) * 200
       when 'b'
         days * 250
       when 'c'
         (days / 3) * 700 + (days % 3) * 300
       when 'd'
         days * 500
       else
         puts 'Unknown hotel.'
       end
```